# Install self-signed SSL certificate correctly (for use in Node.js)

Tags: macos, ssl, certificate, https, openssl

I've been trying to create a self-signed certificate, use it in a simple Node.js server, and install it into the system to the system trusted. However, something is not working, the 'SSL certificate installing' in particular, so here are my steps:

1. Create a certificate, with:
   `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes`
   The certificate should be a `.pem`, since Node.js' `https` module demands one.
2. Write the server app:

   ```
   var https = require('https');  
   var fs = require('fs');

   var options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
   };

   https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
     res.writeHead(200);
     res.end("hello world\n");
   }).listen(8000);
   ```
3. Install the certificate (OS X):
   From what I've read online, I added the `cert.pem` to the System certificates, right-clicked on it and opened information, and could then change it to being trusted.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What does 'is not working' mean exactly?

Comment: @nKn I just tested it with Safari and curl, it seems to work fine there (without any warnings), but Chrome still says 'NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID'

Comment: So, what's the Subject Common Name in your cert? And, does it match the hostname in the URL you're feeding into Chrome?

Comment: Make also sure that the name is not only an unqualified name like 'hostname' but instead FQDN like 'hostname.example.com'.

Comment: Well I would like to use the certificate for `localhost`, since it works in Safari but not in Firefox and Chrome, could someone give instructions how to generate a self-signed certificate for `localhost` and install it in the right place so all browsers trust it? The certificate should be a `.pem` as mentioned above.

Comment: Never mind, found the problem, I was creating the certificates with the wrong Subject Common Name, I wasn't quite sure what it meant and such, working now

Comment: FYI, although it still works, you're not "supposed" to use the Common Name to specify the hostname any more— you should always use Subject Alternative Name extensions even if you only have one. (In the past, you only needed to use SANs if you were using one cert for many hostnames.) However, openssl does not make it convenient to generate a certificate with SANs, so if putting the hostname in the CN works for you, then that's okay also.

Comment: I got sick and tired of learning the SSL implementation of all the various systems I work with: I put everything behind Nginx and I'm done. Just setup your SSL on it.